# Nginx timeout settings revert to default settings

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have Nginx + uWSGI + Docker for Python Flask API.

I want to change Nginx timeouts settings as below:

```
location / {
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;
  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  send_timeout 300;
  uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_pass http://app_service:5000;
  proxy_redirect default;
}
```

But, I can't running the settings and nginx settings revert to default(timeout is 60 second)
I executed restart nginx many time over.

I don't know why nginx settings revert to default.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
processes = 8
enable-threads=true
threads = 2
thunder-lock = true
disable-logging=True
http = :5000
chdir = /api/
wsgi-file = app/__init__.py
callable = app
harakiri = 600
; hot reload for dev
py-autoreload = 1
```

### Tried

#### 1. Changed Nginx Settings

```
        location / {
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_send_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            send_timeout 600;
            uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
            proxy_pass http://app_service:5000;
            proxy_redirect default;
        }
```

#### 2. Docker Restart Run

```
docker-compose up
```

#### 3. Executed Curl

### Expecting

I want to change Nginx timeouts settings!
someone please tell me what I can do to overcome this?

Comment: To change Nginx configuration you have to rebuild the image. The nginx.conf is added to the image during the build and doesn't change during the restart. If you need do it without build you have to mount file from you host to docker

Comment: Thank you for your help!!
I was able to resolved this problem.